# Text fade in with SVG

Tags: html, css

What I want to happen is when you roll over the image, the vector shows up but I also want text to show up as well. Right now, the text is there but it's consistently there. I only want it to appear when you hover over the image.

```css
svg{
  background:url('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/lunifer-kingdom/images/f/fb/Wolf_howling_at_moon.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140105045552');
  background-size:cover;
  width:40vmin; height:auto;
  display:block;
}

h5 {
  height: auto;
  width: 280px;  
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -105px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

text {
  font-size:350px;
  transition:font-size .4s ease-out;
  font-weight:900;
  font-family:arial;
}

svg:hover text{
  transition:font-size .4s ease-in;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 50 50" width="50" height="50">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="49">
      <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="49" height="49" fill="#fff"/>
      <text x="18" text-anchor="middle" y="50" dy="0">D</text>
      <text x="23" id="ltrV" text-anchor="middle" y="50" dy="0">A</text>
      <text x="28" text-anchor="middle" y="50" dy="0">R</text>
      <text x="33" text-anchor="middle" y="50" dy="0">K</text>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="49" height="49" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="1" fill="#C0C0C0"/>
  <div id="overlay">
    <h5><center>text</center></h5>
</svg>
```

Comment: Are you referring to "text" tag or the "text" which is inside h5 tag? If you can clarify I can certainly help.

Comment: The text that is inside the h5 tag

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Please find below the solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fiddle to solve your problem.
[Solution fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/38cn7a0h/15/)

Further I'd like to inform you that, in your layout you have put HTML div tag inside SVG tag, which is not a good approach. Even in must have case, you should add HTML tags inside SVG using **foreignObject** element. Please refer this link for more info on this :https://bl.ocks.org/Jverma/2385cb7794d18c51e3ab

What I did is put this code outside SVG and gave it opacity 0:

```
<div id="overlay">
  <h5><center>text</center></h5>
</div>
```

And making opacity 1 on hover using this code:

```
svg:hover ~ #overlay {
  transition: opacity .7s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for not only your help but your insight as well!! I am very grateful.